# Change datatype of array in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, dtype

I get this error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (3000, 525571) and data type float64
```

for this codeline:

```
Qday = Q.resample('D').sum()
```

Befor this happend i got the nearly the same error on another line, but there i found a solution:

```
Q = pd.DataFrame(Q_tmp, index=Th.index).astype(np.float32) #MemoryError!
```

float32 has to be enough for me, but how can i set the array to use this type?

or can i globally change the default from float64 to float32?

Comment: Try `Q=pd.DataFrame(Q_tmp, index=Th.index, dtype=np.float32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code after the numpy import, it works. :-)

```
import numpy as np
_oldarray = np.array
def array32(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'dtype' not in kwargs: 
        kwargs.update(dtype=float32)
    _oldarray(*args, **kwargs)
np.array = _oldarray
```